# Histogram in R combining first two values

Tags: r, histogram

I am drawing a histogram in R, and the first two frequencies are being combined into one bin which I do not want.  There are seven possible values in the data and I would like 7 bins, not 6.

[image: Histogram]

The info from the histogram drawn by R is,

```
$breaks
[1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

$counts
[1] 27  6  5  4  1 11

$density
[1] 0.50000000 0.11111111 0.09259259 0.07407407 0.01851852 0.20370370

$mids
[1]  9.5 10.5 11.5 12.5 13.5 14.5

$xname
[1] "data$hour"

$equidist
[1] TRUE

attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
```

The issue is in $counts, they should be:

```
9-20
10-7
11-6
12-5  
13-4
14-1
15-11
```

The data and command for histogram and info generation is:

```
temp <- c(9, 9, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 9, 9, 9, 10, 9, 13, 13, 15, 15, 9, 
9, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 15, 15, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 9, 10, 10, 12, 
15, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 15, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 15, 15, 
9, 9, 15)

hist(temp)
histinfo = hist(temp)
histinfo
```

How can this be corrected?  My thought is to count the occurrences and draw a barplot, but that seems like overkill since hist is already built in.  I have tried changing breaks to no avail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `breaks` when drawing a histogram.

Personally, I would tabulate the data by hand and draw a barplot. Which may or may not be what you're really after.

```
library(reshape)
temp.melt <- melt(table(temp))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(temp.melt, aes(x = temp, y = value)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roman.  This certainly does it, though it seems like more than would be necessary.  But it is looking like I am incorrect.

Comment: I am implementing the bar chart after reading John's comments below regarding hist not being great for publication.  This is also a nice time for me to start to use ggplot.  The graphics do look much better.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `table` function with `barplot`

```
> barplot(table(temp))
```

[image]

Comment: Down and dirty and simple.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When using hist you need breaks to bracket both ends if you want every single item. Therefore, the following will work.

```
hist(temp, breaks = 8:15)
```

If you don't like the 8 on the x-axis you'd have to suppress it and then draw the x-axis

```
hist(temp, breaks = 8:15, xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, 8:14+0.5, 9:15)
```

Unfortunately, the built in `hist` function should probably be used primarily for exploration and not publication so if you know that you called the function with arguments like `right = TRUE` then it should be clear to you what the output of the first graph means and easily interpreted (i.e. clearly there is nothing below 8).

Comment: Thanks John.  8 is not a valid value but it shows up on the histogram when done this way.  Can it be done without the 8 showing up?  The histogram does now have the correct number of bins.

Answer (score 1):

Though this has been answered, I find this to be the **simplest** while also producing the **best looking** default chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot( factor(temp) )
```

Comment: This is certainly the simplest and best looking.  I was under the impression R users disliked qplot.  Is that not the case?  I have no experience with it.

Comment: I think `qplot` is fine.  It is a good tool with sane defaults, plus you can "add" all the other modifications to it just like the `ggplot` function.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I contend this is a bug.  Under the default arguments, the breakpoints are supposed to be right-closed, left open.  Based on the documentation, for `breaks=c(9, 10, 11, 12,13,14,15)`, breakpoints should be
(9, 10], (10, 11], (11,12], (12,13], (13,14], (14,15].  Which would mean that the 9's wouldn't be plotted at all.  It seems that `hist` is deciding that `include.lowest=TRUE` (despite the fact that argument is ignored unless you provide `breaks` a vector), so that the first interval is actually [9, 10].

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue just recently and had no other option than to use the HIST plot.  My data started at zero but it kept combining the first two sets as described above.  After playing with this for quite a while trying to set the breaks manually with no affect I was finally able to get this to work correctly by starting the break with a negative value (-).  breaks=c(-1:9) ended up working for me.  I hope that helps with your issue too.

Gary